# Querying large amounts of terms without expanding maxClauseCount

Tags: elasticsearch

In a data flow of mine, I am trying to retrieve a subset of documents from a previous terms aggregation, but hitting the maxClauseCount limit within my ES cluster. The follow up query is along these lines:

```
GET dataset/_search
{
  "size": 2000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        (a filter or two)...,
        {
          "terms":{ 
              "otherid":[
                  "789e18f2-bacb-4e38-9800-bf8e4c65c206",
                  "8e6967aa-5b98-483e-b50f-c681c7396a6a",
                  ...
              ]
           }
         }
      ]}
   }
}
```

In my research I've come across a lookup - which sadly we can't use - as well as the ids query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

From experimentation, it appears that the ids query doesn't share the limit the terms query has (potentially it's not converted into terms clauses). Do any of you know if there's a good way to achieve similar functionality to the ids query without using the ids fields.

My version of ES is 5.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using terms use the Terms filter it will solve the issue

OR
index.query.bool.max_clause_count: increase to higher value(*Not Recommended)

http://george-stathis.com/2013/10/18/setting-the-booleanquery-maxclausecount-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: Hi Prasad, thank you for the speedy feedback! Currently, it appears using a terms filter (or terms within the filter context) is the best idea.
One worry I had was the following: 

_Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching._

Do you know how to prevent it from being cached? I can't seem to find a hint to do so in the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure it's true... I've run a query in a filter contect  (terms filter) and it still throws `maxClauseCount`...